# Why does imagesc change colormap (MATLAB)

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, grayscale

I want to use `imagesc` to crop and display a black and white (grayscale?) image.  However, it keeps displaying the image in rgb, making it look like it came from an infra-red camera!  Any tips for preserving the original colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the color map.  After you run `imagesc` use `colormap('Gray')`. You can set default colormap to current colormap using `colormap('default')`

Comment: Though I'm still curious about why it chose to display my Gray image in RGB!

Comment: @blaughli: Because your "Gray image" is likely actually an indexed color image (i.e., a 2-D matrix, rather than a 3-D RGB image) where the values in the image array are meaningless without an associated colormap. This is pretty much the default for most Matlab functions.

Comment: If you want an actual "Gray image" you can use RGB images. The three channels need to be identical: `IMG=repmat(rand(100),[1 1 3]);` `imagesc(IMG);`. Of course this takes more memory...

Comment: In addition, you can set the default colormap to the current colormap using `colormap('default')` - so once you have done `colormap gray` once, set it to default and the rest of your non-rgb figures will use this. More info: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html

Comment: Thanks Hugh, that's a great tip!